# Why the selectable not working to a group of circles in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, fabricjs, web-frontend

I have this circle object:

```
    function makeCircle(left, top, line1, line2, lineId, stationIndex, stationID) {
    var c = new fabric.Circle({
        left: left,
        top: top,
        strokeWidth: 0.2,
        radius: 1.5,
        fill: '#ffffff',
        stroke: '#666',
        // isMoving: false,
        selectable: true,
    });
    c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = true;
    c.stationID = stationID;
    c.stationIndex = stationIndex;

    c.line1 = line1;
    c.line2 = line2;

    return c;
}
```

I run in a loop , and insert some circles to a group by id of a line.
(every line has id ) :

```
circleGroup[lineId] = new fabric.Group([],{selectable: false,});
var circle = makeCircle(x, y, null, line, lineId, 0, circle1Id);


circleGroup[lineId].add(circle);
```

I want when click on edit() function, the circles in circleGroup[lineId] (lineId = 10120 for exemple ) can be selectable.

```
   function edit(lineId) {
   circleGroup[lineId].selectable = true;
   canvas.renderAll();

}
```

But not happen nothing. the circles not moving when I click on them and try to move.

what the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're after. Do you want the circles to become selectable/interactive, or do you want the circle groups to be selectable/interactive?

It looks like your edit function is making the `circleGroup[lineID]` selectable. Your code above doesn't show the circleGroup being made un-selectable.

If what you want is to make each of the objects in the `circleGroup` selectable. Try:

```
function edit(lineId) {
    var group = circleGroup[lineId]
    for (var i=0; i<group._objects.length; i++){
        group._objects[i].selectable = true;
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Note that when you click on one of your circles it will still be inside a group, so any interaction with the selection (drag, scale, rotate, etc) will be applied to the group.

If you want to make each circle interactive, you'll need to ungroup them first. Try following this: [Grouping and Ungrouping Fabric.js objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904999/grouping-and-ungrouping-fabric-js-objects)